# QGIS Print Layout doesn't show elevation labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, print-composer, topography

I'm trying to export a topographic map with elevation labels, but the Print Layout on QGIS is not showing the labels, only the lines. Why???

**EDIT:** I thought that was clear enough, but here are some further details:
I've created an elevation map with a series of contour lines. I've added elevation labels to these lines. And now, I'd like to export the map via Print-Layout (Project > New Print Layout).
Once on the Print Layout, I select Add Item > Add Map. But only the map is added, only the lines, Not the labels. What am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Normally, the lines should be added. If not, there can be dozens of reasons why that is. Without having some more details about your settings etc., we could only speculate. Can you add a screenshot, showing how the map looks like 1) in the QGIS main window 2) in the print layout?

Comment: @Babel Thanks for your reply. Apparently changing the page size in the Print layout will affect the size and position of the labels.

Comment: @David.  I find it is always best to make the Main/View window the same scale as the layout when trying to determine how labels and symbology will look in the layout.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the thumbs down.
In case anyone is facing the same issue, in my case, the problem was that I was trying to use a different page size in the Print Layout, which causes the labels to change position and size. In my case a custom large size was making the labels so small they were barely visible.